# Filtering SQL table by a changing argument

Tags: sql, filter

I have been trying to filter this database in orther to get a table just with the data in yellow (please see the table attached):

[image: Table attached]

The rules I want to add to get these six rows are: each time the ticker column change I want to get the max maturity of that date.

I tried this code however it doesn't work...:

```
SELECT
    DATE,
    Ticker,
    Maturity,
    Value
FROM
    Tables
WHERE
    MAX(Maturity)
GROUP BY
    Ticker
```

I am not sure that the image attached is visible since when I open my question it doesn't appear. If it doesn't appear please tell me.

Comment: How are the records ordered?  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

Comment: Which flavor? MS SQL, MySQL, MariaDB, Oracle?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Your question pre-supposes an ordering to the data.  Let me assume you have another column with this information.

Then you can just use `lead()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(ticker) over (order by <ordering column>) as next_ticker
      from t
     ) t
where next_ticker is null or next_ticker <> ticker;
```

Comment: Can you please explain usage of lead() and lag() how it actually works internally in short. And also these lag functions do add inconsistency in actual o/p only thing i guess we could use this for referral data purposes just like uve used above

Comment: You can refer to the documentation of the database you are using for information on `lead()`.  I have no idea what you mean by "lag functions do add inconsistency in actual output".

Comment: I mean lag functions obviously have n-1 and 1 null values iterations so i thought like those columns and a lag column would lag by 1 hence inconsistent if used directly

Comment: Thank you for answering, I have been trying to use your code, however, for my system 'LEAD' is not a recognized built-in function name. I also tried with LAG and I get the same result. Is there any alternative to do this?

Comment: @Alvaro . . . This uses standard SQL functions available in almost all databases.  Your question doesn't have a database tag.